# Portable Visual Studio Code on mac not working

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, portability

I want to create my portable Visual Studio on my USB key with MacOS. I followed the instruction from the [official site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable):

> On macOS, you need to place the data folder as a sibling of the application itself. Since the folder will be alongside the application, you need to name it specifically so that VS Code can find it. The default folder name is code-portable-data

> $ xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine Visual\ Studio\ Code.app

So I have the VSCode app in my USB, and create the directory “code-portable-data” alongside it.
But now when I open Visual Studio Code, it crashes. And if I rename or delete “code-portable-data”, it works but it’s not portable.

I hope someone will help me. Thanks!